# R matrix formulation using conditions

Tags: r

"a" data frame looks like

```
v1   v2
 1   1
 2   2
 3   23 
 4   4 
 6   1
 7   1
 8   2
 11  70
```

"b" looks like

```
v1  v2  v3
1   2   3
6   7   8
```

how we can merge data from a to matrix b

results should be like

```
v1   v2   v3
1    2    23
1    1    2
```

Comment: Huh? What's the rule for merging in this example?

Comment: i just want to use data from a$v2 to be replaced in b

Comment: Shouldn't the second row be `1/1/2` not `1/2/2` ? As in `replace(b, , a$v2[match(unlist(b), a$v1)])`

Comment: yeah sorry second row is 1/1/2

Comment: Is `a` a `data.frame` and `b` a `matrix`? What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `match` and replace, or overwrite:

```
replace(b, , a$v2[match(unlist(b), a$v1)])
#  v1 v2 v3
#1  1  2 23
#2  1  1  2
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
b[] <- a$v2[match(unlist(b), a$v1)]
b
#  v1 v2 v3
#1  1  2 23
#2  1  1  2
```